# Is there a way in Sharepoint 07, while logged in as site manager to view what your users will see on a page?

Tags: 2007

I am the site manager of a sharepoint 07 site and I want to be able to see what my users will see on a page, like the view without the site settings tab or anything like that. Like is there some type of "user view" button or something anywhere that I am unable to find? And please nobody suggest that I make an extra user account since I can not do that. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option. The only way - without a user account - would be to log out if anonymous access is enabled on your site.

For SharePoint, "User" doesn't mean much. There's a variety of roles - contributor, reader, etc. - and for each role the page may have a different look.